# Bulk Index data in Elasticsearch with sequential IDs

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I am using this code to bulk index all data in Elasticsearch using python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import json
import os
import sys
import sys, json

es = Elasticsearch()   

def load_json(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.json'):
            with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
                yield json.load(open_file)

helpers.bulk(es, load_json(sys.argv[1]), index='v1_resume', doc_type='candidate')
```

I know that if ID is not mentioned ES gives a 20 character long ID by itself, but I want it to get indexed starting from ID = 1 till the number of documents.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: why don't you pass `ID` inside your schema in `load_json` and build your objects with whatever `ID` you like?

Answer (score 2):

In elastic search if you don't pick and `ID` for your document an `ID` is automatically created for you, check here in 
[elastic docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-doc.html#_autogenerating_ids):

```
Autogenerated IDs are 20 character long, URL-safe, Base64-encoded GUID 
strings. These GUIDs are generated from a modified FlakeID scheme which 
allows multiple nodes to be generating unique IDs in parallel with 
essentially zero chance of collision.
```

If you like to have custom ids you need to build them yourself, using similar syntax:

```
[
    {'_id': 1,
     '_index': 'index-name',
     '_type': 'document',
     '_source': {
          "title": "Hello World!",
          "body": "..."}

    },
    {'_id': 2,
     '_index': 'index-name',
     '_type': 'document',
     '_source': {
          "title": "Hello World!",
          "body": "..."}
    }
]

helpers.bulk(es, load_json(sys.argv[1])
```

Since you are decalring the `type` and `index` inside your `schema` you don't have to do it inside `helpers.bulk()` method. You need to change the output of 'load_json' to create list with dicts (like above) to be saved in es ([python elastic client docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html))